# OpenCV Remap From One Location to Another

Tags: image, opencv

I would like to remap a square patch of an image in (x,y,width,height) of (45, 104, 37, 37) to another location (80, 200, 37,37). May I know why are the codes below not right?

```
for (int i =0;i<37;i++) //width
{
    for (int j =0;j<37;j++) //width
    {

    map_x.at<float>(45+i,104+j) = 80+i ;
    map_y.at<float>(45+i,104+j) = 200+j ;
    }
}
```

or,

```
for (int i =45; i <82; i++)
{
    for (int j =104; j<141; j++)
    {
     map_x.at<float>(i,j) = i+37 ;
     map_y.at<float>(i,j) = j+37 ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `map_x.at<float>(i,j) = i+37;` you're storing the *number* i+37 at the *location(index)* `i`. Not the *number at.* Same for the statement following it.

OpenCV has a convenient method involving ROIs.

```
Mat roi = map_x( Rect(45, 104, 37, 37) );
map_x( Rect(80, 200, 37,37) ) = roi;
```